# JDialog modality and class extending

Tags: java, swing, jframe, modal-dialog, jdialog

So, I need to create a class that extends `JDialog`, to remove `JDialog` code from the main functions code.

However, I don't know how to set it's parent `JFrame` after the `JDialog` has been created.

It's usually done by passing the `JFrame` to the constructor, but since it's a custom class, I don't know how to set it to be `JDialog`s parent. I couldn't find any method of type `JDialog.setParent(JFrame);` I hope you understand the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent `Window` (`Frame` or `Dialog`) is called owner in the APIs. You can only mention it in the constructor by calling the super class (JDialog) constructor.

Example:

```
public class SomeDialog extends JDialog {

  public SomeDialog() {
    // see other JDialog constructors for other ways to call this
    super(parentWindow, title, ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
    ...
  }

}
```

You cannot set it later, after your custom `JDialog` has been created.

Comment: I have another question. How to dispose of it in the main function (or any other)?

I have declared it and set to null, later in code I created an instance and joined it with the variable.


After I call

Comment: Calling dispose() will dispose your dialog.

Comment: I hit enter too soon... I call it inside main functions code (in a actionlistener code attached to JButton insidea main). I'm disposing of it from another function. If I don't instance it as soon as it's declared, I get nullpointerexception, and if I instance it, it shows up on screen before it should.

Comment: Nevermind, I gave up idea about excluding it from main class/method, I've just put it back...

Answer (score 4):

You can set the parent in the JDialog's constructor or in a setter method. Then when you create the dialog, you'll know the parent by then and can pass it into the parameter. You can then pass the parameter into the super constructor.

As an aside, I've rarely ever had to extend JDialog, JFrame or any top level window but instead prefer to use them "out of the box" and make them when needed.